# jQuery check if element exists

Tags: jquery

How can I modify the script below so that it doesn't throw an error when the ".fixit" element is not present in the DOM?

```
function fixedHeaders() {
       var el = jQuery('.fixit'),
           offset = el.offset(),
           elHeight = el.height(),
           scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop()
           if (((offset.top + 400) < scrollTop - el.height())) {
               el.addClass('fixedElement');
           }

       if (scrollTop === 0) {
           el.removeClass('fixedElement');
       }
}
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery(window)
       .scroll(fixedHeaders)
       .trigger("scroll");
});
```

Comment: Seriously, was it hard to find the answer when searching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

```
if (!jQuery('.fixit').length) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.fixit').length) {

     var el = jQuery('.fixit'),
           offset = el.offset(),
           elHeight = el.height(),
           scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop()
           if (((offset.top + 400) < scrollTop - el.height())) {
               el.addClass('fixedElement');
           }

       if (scrollTop === 0) {
           el.removeClass('fixedElement');
       }

}
```